# Handling an empty Mono

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, reactive

I am trying to write a reactive function that performs a certain task when the first Mono is non-empty, and a "fallback" task when the Mono is empty. This is what I have so far:

```
static Mono<String> init(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    if ("err".equals(input)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Some exception");
    }

    System.out.println("First Mono: " + input);
    return Mono.just("First Mono: " + input);
}

static Mono<Void> doesSomeStuff(String input) {
    System.out.println("Second Mono: " + input);
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

My first attempt was to specify a `flatMap` call that would handle the valid Mono scenario, and a `switchIfEmpty` call that would handle the empty Mono scenario

```
    /**
     * Wrong! The 3rd line should not be shown! Defer causes empty block to be lazily evaluated
     *
     * First Mono: Hello
     * Second Mono: First Mono: Hello
     * Second Mono: Empty
     */
    Mono<String> firstMono = init("Hello");
    firstMono.flatMap(WebfluxDemoApplication::doesSomeStuff)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> doesSomeStuff("Empty")))
            .block();

    /**
     * Correct! Only the empty branch is executed
     *
     * Second Mono: Empty
     */
    Mono<String> first2Mono = init(null);
    first2Mono.flatMap(WebfluxDemoApplication::doesSomeStuff)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> doesSomeStuff("Empty")))
            .block();
```

However, the output does not align with my expectations. I did some searching and I did find a sequence of operations that DOES work:

```
    /**
     * Correct!
     *
     * First Mono: Hello
     * Second Mono: First Mono: Hello
     */
    Mono<String> first5Mono = init("Hello");
    first5Mono.delayUntil(initVal -> doesSomeStuff(initVal))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> doesSomeStuff("Empty")).cast(String.class))
            .then()
            .block();

    System.out.println("---");

    /**
     * Correct!
     *
     * Second Mono: Empty
     */
    Mono<String> first6Mono = init(null);
    first6Mono.delayUntil(initVal -> doesSomeStuff(initVal))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> doesSomeStuff("Empty")).cast(String.class))
            .then()
            .block();

    System.out.println("---");

    /**
     * Correct! It throws the Exception.
     *
     * Second Mono: Empty
     */
    Mono<String> first7Mono = init("err");
    first7Mono.delayUntil(initVal -> doesSomeStuff(initVal))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> doesSomeStuff("Empty")).cast(String.class))
            .then()
            .block();
```

Can someone explain to me why this works? Why does `delayUntil` work, but not `flatMap`? Why do I have to cast the Mono in the `switchIfEmpty` statement? I believe `then` is used to signal completion by emitting an empty Mono. Does this just work coincidentally, because `doesSomeStuff` return type is `Mono<Void>`?

Comment: Oh yes, that is what I was expecting. I just wanted to make sure the Exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMap` doesn't work because you are always flat-mapping to an empty `Mono`. This means it will always return an empty `Mono`, causing `switchIfEmpty` to always "switch".

`delayUntil` doesn't affect the original `Mono`'s value in any way. It just makes it emit its value a little later.

I do think `flatMap` is more readable though, so you could do something like this:

```
mono.flatMap(x -> doesSomeStuff(x).thenReturn(x))
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> doesSomeStuff("empty")).then(Mono.empty()))
        .block();
```

`thenReturn` makes sure that `flatMap` doesn't "eat up" the value. `then(Mono.empty())` is then used to convert the `Mono<Void>` into an empty `Mono<String>`.

Your `cast` works here because `doesSomeStuff` always returns an empty `Mono`. I suppose you could call that a "coincidence". `then()` is not really relevant here - it just gets rid of the `String` value that you would have gotten if the original `Mono` does have a value. If `doesSomeStuff` returns a non-empty `Mono`, you'd need some other way to make it a `Mono<String>`, e.g. `then(Mono.empty())`.

That said, if `doesSomeStuff` does return a non-empty `Mono` of another type, you can just `flatMap` and then `switchIfEmpty` like you did in your first attempt. In this case, `flatMap` will preserve the existence of a value.

If you don't actually need the value of the original `Mono` to pass to `doesSomeStuff`, you can just use `hasElement`:

```
mono.hasElement().flatMap( hasElem ->
    hasElem ? doesSomeStuff("intVal") : doesSomeStuff("Empty")
).block();
```

Comment: My original assumption was that I wanted to do a switch based on the output of the `init` method. e.g. if init produces a non-empty value, it will execute the stuff in the flatMap, otherwise it will "switch" to the `switchIfEmpty` loop. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: @user1927638 you already showed a working solution in your question, and the first code snippet in my answer should also work. What exactly is the problem?